# The load event of an iframe isn't fired while Content-Disposition header is configured as attachment

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, dom-events

First of all I just want the `load` event to be fired only in Mozilla Firefox.

I've already tried different ways, but all I came to know is that load event of an iframe will only gets fired while the 'Content-Disposition' header is configured as 'inline'.

Is there any other event by which i came to know that the iframe dialog box pops up and ask user to save the file?

Please have look into the following implementation of mine and help me to get the proper solution.

HTML code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="FileName.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "button" value="Download" onclick = "javascript:downloadFile('http://localhost/data.php');"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code :

```
var downloadFile = function(url) {
// create hidden iframe
var id = "xyz";
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
frame.id = id;
frame.name = id;
frame.style="visibility:hidden;display:none";
document.body.appendChild(frame);

var callback = function() {
    alert('completed');
};

frame.onload = callback;
frame.src = url;
};
```

PHP code :

```
<?php
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0'); // set expiration time
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

// Set Content Disposition header
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=some.txt');
// Set content type header
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

$file = "some.txt";

if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");

header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header('Expires: 0');
readfile($file);
?>
```

Hoping for a proper solution.

Comment: Why would you use an iframe for a file download, and what for do you need an event when the download dialog pops up?

Comment: because i want to pop up a confirmation window to the user.
and i want 'load' event to hide the load mask appeared up till the response is arrived.

Comment: Confirmation of what exactly?

Comment: confirmation about the 'save' path on users machine.
or may be he can cancel the entire operation him self by click 'cancel' button on the pop up window.

Comment: They can do all that with the normal download dialog that their browser presents them with when a file download is started, so I don’t see any need for using an iframe or a custom confirmation window really …

Comment: chat is possible for you ?
so i can explain you in a better way...

Comment: @BhavinBathani Were you ever able to get this working?